# Is it possible to paint using Canvas in Andgengine (android framework for game)

Tags: android, graphics, draw, curve, andengine

Basically want to draw curve paths when user touches (somewhat like flight control app). Using the paint API it is possible to draw on a Canvas ([finger paint example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)). But I am unable to draw on a andengine view.

Any suggestions on how to draw a curve on android using andengine 
library?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most popular Andengine games is Chalk Ball Lite which uses such an effect very successfully.   Unfortunately, according to informaation from the developer that I have seen elsewhere on StackOverflow, he had to accomplish this using a "workaround" that created curved paths as a series of rectangles.  Depending on what you will be using these paths for you might be able to either use the series of rectangles methods or possible a series of points/particles.

Sorry I can't offer much specific information, but I think the answer is "no but you can do it yourself with some work"